# static non-template method in template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to add a static function to a template class that is accessible without passing template parameters first. Is that possible?

```
namespace foo {
  template <typename T>
  class bar {
  public:
    static void eggs();
  };
}

foo::bar<some_t>::eggs();  // works
foo::bar::eggs();  // does not work
```

I would like to avoid moving `eggs()` to the `foo` namespace or to create a new namespace for it (eg. `foo::bar_::eggs()`, ugh).

Answer (score 6):

No.  That is not how template classes work.  What you want to do is not possible in C++.

Comment: No, you cannot do it. But you can always use typedefs to shorten the name.
typedef foo::bar<some_t> Tbar; 
Tbar::eggs();

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `foo::bar` does not name any type, but solely a template that can be used to create other types.

Besides using typedefs/type aliases (through `using`), you can perhaps have a non-templated base class for you templates, and then put your static members there.  If you use public inheritance, changing the static member in any of the templated classes will change in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting with your code:

> I want to add a static function to a template class that is accessible
>   without passing template parameters first. Is that possible?

```
namespace foo {
  template <typename T>
  class bar {
  public:
    static void eggs();
  };
}

foo::bar<some_t>::eggs();  // works
foo::bar::eggs();  // does not work
```

> I would like to avoid moving eggs() to the foo namespace or to create
>   a new namespace for it (eg. foo::bar_::eggs(), ugh).

I have come to the conclusion that, the first instance of

```
foo::bar<some_t>::eggs(); // works while
foo::bar::eggs(); // doesn't
```

Is due to the fact that when working with templates, anything within the class has to be relative to a specific object, even if you do not want the function to be. I even tried using function pointers and tried to save them to template class and without no avail I couldn't even get that to compile. I do not see much of an option for you in this situation. There maybe other tricks out there that someone might know, but not from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the template parameter optional and you can define a specialized template. Like this:

```
namespace foo {

template <typename T = void> class bar {
public:
  static void eggs() { cout << "First there was the egg" << endl; }
};

template <> class bar<void> {
public:
  static void eggs() {
    cout << "Then there was the chicken... or was it?" << endl;
  }
};
}

auto main() -> int {
  foo::bar<int>::eggs(); // egg
  foo::bar<>::eggs();    // chicken

  return 0;
}
```